# supportActionBar is getSupportActionBar?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently learning Kotlin and I'm trying to understand something. The tutorial I'm following is making a toolbar. We made the toolbar in the layout xml file then used setSupportActionBar() to find it. I can see that setSupportActionBar() is part of the AppCompatActivity class.

We then use supportActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener{}. What I'm confused about is where is this supportActionBar variable coming from? It's not defined in any of the code on the course. When I highlight it tells me it comes from androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar but that it is actually "getSupportActionBar()". When I ctrl + click the variable, it shows me getSupportActionBar() in AppCompatActivity.

But for the life of me I can't figure out where this "supportActionBar" object is coming from. I can't find it in the android docs or anywhere. I can see the ActionBar class has the getSupportActionBar() method and the setSupportActionBar is coming from AppCompatActivity. But where does this variable come from? How am I supposed to know if such things exist if they aren't in the docs?

Not sure if this makes any sense. Here is the code, please ignore the note
ExerciseActivity.kt

```
package com.example.a7minutesworkout

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.a7minutesworkout.databinding.ActivityExerciseBinding
import com.example.a7minutesworkout.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

class ExerciseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var binding : ActivityExerciseBinding? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityExerciseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding?.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding?.toolbarExercise)

    if(supportActionBar != null){
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    binding?.toolbarExercise?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }
}}
```

the layout xml file, activity_exercise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ExerciseActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarExercise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I might be able to understand if i was having to catch the output of getSupportActionBar() in a variable something like:

```
var supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar()
```

But that isn't in the code on the course. This "supportActionBar" variable seems to just magically exist. I feel like I'm missing some key thing about kotlin. I have learned java before and I feel like I'm missing some big piece to the kotlin puzzle. I'm not even sure if "supportActionBar" is a variable? It just has the lower case camel case so I assume it is. Can anyone fill me in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters),

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters
> (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument
> methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in
> Kotlin.

Which means that the Kotlin compiler will generate a synthetic `supportActionBar` property for `AppCompatActivity` if it notices that this type has `getSupportActionBar()` and `setSupportActionBar()` methods.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange there's no mention of it in the Android Docs. I guess with other classes you'd have to check the java file for get/set methods and do trial and error to see if kotlin had generated some synthetic properties like supportActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

Java has the concept of getters and setters to hide the internal workings of a class from an external caller. This is generally a good practice, but with the way Java implemented it, it creates lots of boilerplate code which takes up useless space on your screen. Kotlin hides this by replacing `getSupportActionBar()` and `setSupportActionBar()` with a variable called `supportActionBar`. Behind the scenes, it actually calls `setSupportActionBar()` when you do `supportActionBar = something` and `getSupportActionBar()` when you do `val myVar = supportActionBar`.

A very helpful thing to understand the inner workings of Kotlin is to convert your Kotlin code to Java. You can do that with "Tools" -> "Kotlin" -> "Show Kotlin Bytecode" -> "Decompile". For instance, if I do this in Kotlin:

```
class StackOverflowDemo {
    var test: String = ""
}

class CallingClass{
    fun myFunction() {
        val demo = StackOverflowDemo()
        val myVariable = demo.test
        demo.test = "Another string"
    }
}
```

it transpiles to this in Java (metadata and imports removed for conciseness):

```java
public final class StackOverflowDemo {
   @NotNull
   private String test = "";

   @NotNull
   public final String getTest() {
      return this.test;
   }

   public final void setTest(@NotNull String var1) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(var1, "<set-?>");
      this.test = var1;
   }
}

public final class CallingClass {
   public final void myFunction() {
      StackOverflowDemo demo = new StackOverflowDemo();
      String myVariable = demo.getTest();
      demo.setTest("Another string");
   }
}
```

[Here are the appropriate Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) if you want to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems odd that there's no mention of this automatically generated variable in the Android Docs. You can use "setSupportActionBar(binding?.toolbarExercise)" OR "var supportActionBar = binding?.toolbarExercise" but there's no mention of any of this anywhere in the docs. I guess with other classes you'd just have to check the java file to see if it has get/set methods and do trial and error to see if kotlin has spawned some variables.

Comment: I don't understand. Firstly, Kotlin always spawns those properties (no trial and error necessary) and secondly, don't you have syntax completion available?

Comment: Well I'd need to know what to look for first. As I progress with the learning I'm gonna have to keep looking at classes to see what properties they are spawning. It isn't in the android docs.

Comment: As written in the Kotlin docs, this is actually pretty easy: For every `getSomething()` or `isExpandable()`, a property called `something` or `isExpandable` is generated. There's no guessing here whether or not a property is generated.